# sharepoint 2013 global search center and different zones

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have sharepoint 2013 server farm with alternate access mapping.
I have two zones with URLs:

1. `http://portal` (Default)
2. `https://portal.domain.com` (Internet)

I have a global search center site collection with url http:// portal/sites/search.

I want users from default zone when searching to redirect to `http://portal/sites/search`, while users from internet zone redirect to `https://portal.domain.com/sites/search`.
But I can only enter one full URL of search center in search options.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured that i can enter relative link as global search URL. Now all works just fine.
I'm entered /sites/search/pages as my URL and now in all zones users redirects to right URL.

Comment: I have the same issue as your, but whatever zone I'm my search result always go to the default zone url. Even I used the relative url my in global search url.